# API not returning JSON data in desired format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using .Net Core Entity Framework 3.1 for a web catalog application for automobile parts.

I have one simple controller, that returns all `motorParts` for a particular motor.

Here is that simple controller:

```
[HttpGet("GetPartsByMotorId/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MotorParts>>> GetPartsByMotorId(Guid id)
{

   var partsByMotor = await _context.MotorParts.Where(q => q.MotorId == id).OrderBy(c => c.partText).ToListAsync();

    return partsByMotor;
}
```

It is returning the data, but it is in an order that I do not want and with some data duplicated.

The JSON looks like this when returned from the API:

```
[
    {
        "partId": "54",
        "motorId": "3",
        "partText": "Iron Heads",
        "motor": {
            "motorId": "3",
            "motorText": "5.7 HEMI",
            "motorParts": [
                {
                    "partId": "54",
                    "motorId": "3",
                    "partText": "Iron Heads"
                },
                {
                    "partId": "8",
                    "motorId": "3",
                    "partText": "Aluminum Block"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "partId": "8",
        "motorId": "3",
        "partText": "Aluminum Block",
        "motor": {
            "motorId": "3",
            "motorText": "5.7 HEMI",
            "motorParts": [
                {
                    "partId": "8",
                    "motorId": "3",
                    "partText": "Aluminum Block"
                },
                {
                    "partId": "54",
                    "motorId": "3",
                    "partText": "Iron Heads"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

The problem for me, is that it is listing a "part" ( `partId, motorId, partText` ) first, then listing the same "parts" again later on.

But I want it to just list the motor data first, then all the parts for that motor, like this:

```
[
    {
        "motor": {
            "motorId": "3",
            "motorText": "5.7 HEMI",
            "motorParts": [
                {
                    "partId": "8",
                    "motorId": "3",
                    "partText": "Aluminum Block"
                },
                {
                    "partId": "54",
                    "motorId": "3",
                    "partText": "Iron Heads"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Here is the model:

```
public partial class MotorParts
{
    public Guid PartId { get; set; }
    public Guid? MotorId { get; set; }
    public string PartText { get; set; }

    public virtual MotorList Motor { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my database context for that model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MotorParts>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.PartId);

    entity.HasOne(d => d.Motor)
        .WithMany(p => p.MotorParts)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.MotorId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_carList_makeList");

    entity.ToTable("MotorParts");

    entity.Property(e => e.PartId)
        .HasColumnName("PartId");

    entity.Property(e => e.MotorId)
        .HasColumnName("MotorId");

    entity.Property(e => e.PartText)
        .HasColumnName("PartText");
});
```

So I was wondering if there is a way to get the JSON format I want without changing my model too much.  Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide correct transformation. Also this query needs client-side grouping.

```cs
var dataQuery = 
   from mi in _context.MotorParts
   where mp.MotorId == id
   select new 
   {
      Motor = new 
      { 
          motorId = mp.MotorId.Value,
          motorText = mp.Motor.MotorText 
      },
      MotorPart = new 
      { 
          partId = mp.PartId,
          motorId = mp.MotorId.Value,
          partText = mp.PartText
      }
   }

var partsByMotor = 
   from mp in await dataQuery.ToListAsync()
   group mp.MotorPart by mp.Motor into g
   select new 
   {
       motorId = g.Key.motorId,
       motorText = g.Key.motorText,
       motorParts = g.OrderBy(x => x.partText).ToArray()
   };

return partsByMotor.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you investigated ways to decorate your properties with attributes in such a way that you can control the order?
Much like can be achieved with the NewtonSoft Json Property Order.   https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your desired return looks to just be a `Motor` object return that includes all related `MotorPart` objects. There is some issue here with your model design as you've got a `MotorParts` class that is supposed to represent a single individual `MotorPart`, correct? I can't tell if `MotorParts` is supposed to be a collection of objects itself, or whether multiple `MotorPart` objects are in a collection. What was your intention for the class? I assume it's meant to represent an individual `MotorPart`? If so, it should really be named `MotorPart`.

As it is, EF is treating each `MotorParts` object as an individual motor part and storing each in the MotorParts table. Was this just a naming mistake on your part? When you run the query, you're getting an `List<MotorParts>` collection returned. Each element in the list contains a reference to the related `Motor` object, which also has a reference back to the motor parts. This seems like a rather poor design choice, based on what you said the desired result is.

The simplest recommendation would be to remove the `Motor` property from your MotorParts class and just keep the `MotorId` property. That would remove the redundant reference back to the motor parts. Still, this query is returning a collection of objects. It is NOT returning a single Motor object containing the related MotorParts.

If you want to return the single `Motor` object along with all of it's `MotorParts` then you need to run the query against the `Motors` table instead.